What does waveOutGetPosition do when the sample counter rolls over?
The waveOutGetPosition function can be configured to write the number of elapsed samples to a MMTIME structure.  The field this information is written to is of type DWORD, which, in Win32, is a unsigned 32-bit integer.
If my math is right, at 44100Hz, this means that the counter should roll over once per 27 hours:
4294967296 / 44100 / 60 / 60 = 27.0532079617032
What would happen in such a situation?  While it doesn't exactly describe the situation, I guess waveOutGetPosition might return MMSYSERR_NOMEM?  Or would the sample timer lock at 4294967295?  Or would it roll over to 0?

How would you store a 27-hour long recording at 44100Hz? How many petabytes of storage would that require? I'm quite sure that you'd run into other issues before you ever got close to worrying about what happens with rollover.

My current use case for waveOut is generating, preparing, writing, unpreparing then re-using short buffers of 1-2 seconds.  I was under the impression that this was effectively re-cycling memory rather than requiring a contiguous block of 4 billion samples.  In any case, my process's memory usage appears to be static (though that can be misleading).  But the sample counter increases continually, it doesn't reset to 0 at the start of each buffer.

According to the Doc:waveOutGetPosition The position is set to zero when the device is opened or reset. In my opinion, it won't roll over to 0, when the number of waveform-audio samples increases.

@jameswilddev Seems like something that you can easily test yourself. Just make a simple app that outputs an audio buffer repeatedly for 27 hours, and see what happens when the DWORD reaches its highest value.  A DWORD is an unsigned value, and unsigned values overflow to 0. This is well-defined behavior. But who knows whether the multimedia API decides to let that overflow happen. Maybe it will overflow, or maybe it will just stop counting.  Test it.

Manually testing this scenario indicates that the position rolls over:
Progress: 4294964450
Progress: 4294965179
Progress: 4294965904
Progress: 4294966636
Progress: 89
Progress: 826
Progress: 1546
Progress: 2298

While in this specific test run the position never hit 0, the rate at which the position was sampled (60Hz) was significantly less than the wave's sample rate (44100Hz) - I would assume that it did, in fact, roll over through 0.

While not specifically asked for, I presume these are the issues you are actually concerned about: unsigned overflow is well defined. Assuming that you have two MMTIME values (start and end), then end.sample - start.sample will always evaluate to the distance between those time points, even when the counter wrapped around. If you need to know whether the counter wrapped around, bool wrap_around = end.sample < start.sample; will tell you.

I might be misunderstanding here but your comment implies that I have code subtracting MMTIME values from one another.
That is not the case, I am printing the exact values returned by the waveOutGetPosition function here.  The rollover is happening within the winmm library itself, not any code I have written.
I know how unsigned integer rollover works - the question was whether winmm would roll the counter over, or do something else (e.g. returning an error code).  Because that wasn't clear from documentation and Jeaninez - MSFT above specifically stated that it would not roll over.

My comment established that rollover semantics are free from information loss, hence they are used by default (GetTickCount is another example). I don't know why "Jeaninez - MSFT" felt the need to voice an opinion.
